# ¿Como evitar el redireccionamiento del formulario? - PERL

Tags: html, perl

Tengo un formulario el cual he utilizado para hacer una calculadora básica pero al momento de ejecutar el script `CGI` en `PERL` me redirecciona a una página blanca y solo imprime la respuesta.

Quisiera que al momento de presionar el botón `submit` se ejecutara el script `CGI` de `PERL` y sin cambiar de página me imprimiera la respuesta debajo del botón `submit` o en algún espacio de la página sin esta tener que redireccionarse a la página blanca.

Mi formulario es este :

```
 <form id="formu" action="multiplicar.cgi" method="POST" class="form register">
  <h2 class="form_titulo"> Calculadora </h2> 
     <div class="contenedor-inputs">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="numero1"  id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el número  " maxlength="10" class="input-100" required    />  
      <center>
       <select name="operador">
           <option value="sumar">+</option>
           <option value="restar">-</option>
           <option value="multiplicar">x</option>
           <option value="dividir">/</option>
       </select>
       </center>
       <input type="text" name="numero2"  id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el número  " maxlength="10" class="input-100" required    />   
<center>
   <input class="form-btn" type="submit" id="btnenviar" value="Ingresar"/>
       </center>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Y el script `CGI` de `PERL` es el siguiente:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;` #se utiliza el modo estricto de perl
use CGI;` #Libreria CGI de perl
# Recoge los parametros del formulario
my $cgi = new CGI;
my $n1 = $cgi->param('numero1');
my $n2 = $cgi->param('numero2');
my $op = $cgi->param('operador');


# comprueba si los parametros son numeros
if ($n1 !~ /[0-9]+$/ or $n2 !~ /[0-9]+$/ ) {
  print $cgi->header("text/html");
  print "Error ha ingresado datos incorrectos";
  return;
}
# declara variable total
my $total;

# se verifica la opción que el usuario eligio para mostrar el resultado
if($op eq "sumar"){
  $total=$n1+$n2;
}elsif($op eq "restar"){
  $total=$n1-$n2;
}elsif($op eq "multiplicar"){
  $total=$n1*$n2;
}elsif($op eq "dividir"){
if($n2<=0){
  $total="No se puede dividir entre 0"
}else{
  $total=$n1/$n2;}
}

# cabecera http
print $cgi->header("text/html");

#muestra el resultado

print "El resultado es " . $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

En la parte de pintado del resultado es donde tienes que enviar TODO el código HTML de la página que quieres que se vea. Y con el resultado en la parte que quieras que aparezca.

Comment: no sé como poner toda esa página... lo he intentado pero no me funciona podría darme un ejemplo

Comment: Debe hacer un print con el contenido textual de la página en HTML. O usar las funciones que generan HTML que trae el módulo CGI. Si se trata de una gran cantidad de texto estático, es mejor usar el primer método:
print "<html>\n";
print "<head>\n";
# ...
print "</head>\n";
print "<body>";
# ...

Comment: Mira el ejemplo final de http://perlenespanol.com/tutoriales/cgi/upload_de_archivos.html , al final del código.